# Маска на выбор интервала дат при помощи плагина IMask js

Tags: javascript, datepicker, inputmask, mask

Использую плагин Imask js, совместно с air-datepicer.

Сделал по примеру из документации, но что-то пошло не так. Не дописывает последний символ в маске.
Прошу помощи разобраться в проблеме.

Ссылку на пример прикладываю

```
[https://codepen.io/haredus/pen/dyZNEJZ][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено следующее:
Используем маску в маске. Получилось следующее:

```
var maxDate = new Date(),
    minDate = new Date();
    minDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);                 // От сегодняшнего дня
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 2200); // Не больше 2200 дней

    var dateMaskOptions = {
        mask: Date,
        pattern: 'd{.}`m{.}`Y'
        blocks: {
            d: {
                mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
                from: 1,
                to: 31,
                maxLength: 2,
            },
            m: {
                mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
                from: 1,
                to: 12,
                maxLength: 2,
            },
            Y: {
                mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
                from: minDate.getFullYear(),
                to: maxDate.getFullYear(),
            }
        },
        // define date -> str convertion
        format: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDate();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = date.getFullYear();

            if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
            if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;

            return [day, month, year].join(".");
        },
        // define str -> date convertion
        parse: function (str) {
            var yearMonthDay = str.split(".");
            return new Date(yearMonthDay[2], yearMonthDay[1] - 1, yearMonthDay[0]);
        },

        // optional interval options
        min: minDate,
        max: maxDate,

        autofix: true,  // defaults to `false`, see details

        // also Pattern options can be set
        lazy: false,

        // and other common options
        overwrite: true  // defaults to `false`
    };

    var dateMask = IMask(FIELD_DATA, {
        mask: [
            {
                mask: "date1 - date2",
                lazy: true,
                blocks: {
                    date1: dateMaskOptions,
                    date2: dateMaskOptions
                }
            },
        ]
    });
```